# Combining two images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to combine two UI Images and make a new image called mainImage. One of the images is a solid background, backgroundImage, while the other is a curve created by a path, brushimage. For what I have right now the background image draws but the curve image won't. This first method creates an image for the curve image with a path.

```
- (void)drawBrezierPath:(UIBezierPath *)thePath onto:(UIImage *)image {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    [self.brushColor setStroke];
    [thePath stroke];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

This one creates the background:

```
- (void)drawBackground
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
    UIBezierPath *rectpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
    [self.backgroundColor setFill];
    [rectpath fill];
    backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

And then they are combined using this:

```
- (void)drawMainImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    //[self drawBackground];
    [backgroundImage drawInRect:self.frame];
    [brushImage drawInRect:self.frame];
    mainImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

But only the background shows up. When I comment out the line that draws the background then the line is shown but it doesn't draw when the background gets drawn. When I switch the order that the background/brushimage are drawn it doesn't make a difference the brushImage still doesn't show up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you merge brushImage and BackgroundImage in third function, but you create "image" instead of "brushImage" in first function, shouldn't you set it to "brushImage" ?

Comment: Somewhere else in the code I call the first method with brushImage as the image. Switching brushImage with image does work though, I'm wondering why it doesn't work when I call it with brushImage.